# Show username in Meteor React component

Tags: javascript, meteor, reactjs

One of my React component is my main layout, where I display a nav bar with the currently logged-in user. The problem is that `Meteor.user()` is `undefined` when the Component is first rendered. How would I go and properly render my nav bar once the user object has been loaded/published?

#### MainLayout.jsx

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

export default class MainLayout extends Component {
  render() {
    return (<div>{ Meteor.user().username }</div>);
  }
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Meteor.user() should be part of [container component](https://guide.meteor.com/react.html#using-createContainer). react-meteor-data package should be added to the project.

```
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';
import { createContainer } from 'meteor/react-meteor-data';
import MainLayout from './mainLayout';

export default MainLayoutContainer = createContainer(({ params }) => {
  return {
    user: Meteor.user(),
  };
}, MainLayout);
```

The user will be available as props in the MainLayout component.

Answer (score 1):

To use data from a Meteor collection inside a React component, we can use an Atmosphere package react-meteor-data which allows us to create a "data container" to feed Meteor's reactive data into React's component hierarchy.

> meteor add react-meteor-data

```
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react';
import { createContainer } from 'meteor/react-meteor-data';

class MainLayout extends Component {
  render() {
    return (<div>{ this.props.user.username }</div>);
  }
}

export default MainLayoutContainer createContainer(() => {
  return {
    user: Meteor.user()
  };
}, MainLayout);
```